# C# Enforcing Use of Dictionary Keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, standards

I'm wondering what best practice is for verifying or enforcing the Keys used for a Dictionary object/parameter.

Take for example this method:

```
public override SqlServerQueryBuilder From(Dictionary<string, string> tableReferenceDictionary)
        {

            this.SelectQuery += " FROM " + this.IdentifierStart + tableReferenceDictionary["Database"] + this.IdentifierEnd
                             + "." + this.IdentifierStart + tableReferenceDictionary["Schema"] + this.IdentifierEnd
                             + "." + this.IdentifierStart + tableReferenceDictionary["Table"] + this.IdentifierEnd;

            return this;
        }
```

This method takes a Dictionary parameter, and makes an **assumption** about the keys used. If the caller passes a typo (*"database" instead of "Database"*) then this code will throw an exception. Is there a better way to manage this?

Maybe a different data type that achieves the same thing?

Maybe use a enum and make the key of type enum (`Dictionary<enum, string>`)?

Comment: Yes I think a custom class would be more appropriate than a dictionary.

Comment: a class with a constructor with the 3 fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom class here is more appropriate, so you can enforce all your "keys" (which will be properties in the new class) are filled as expected.

Comment: So say I have a SqlQuerybuilder class building Sql for the rest of the application.

Should the Class be a nested class inside SqlQueryBuilder? Like SqlQueryBuilder.TableReference

Comment: If it will only be useful to the SqlQueryBuilder than yes, a nested class works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. Using `Dictionary<enum, string>` is probably best way to go.